# Unknown command: 'run_gunicorn' with Django, Heroku, and New Relic

Tags: django, heroku, wsgi, gunicorn, newrelic

I am installing an add-on named New Relic (monitoring) on my Django Heroku app, following [this doc](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/python-agent/hosting-services/python-agent-heroku).
After installaling the new relic agent, I was asked to change the Procfile to:

```
web: newrelic-admin run-program python manage.py run_gunicorn -b "0.0.0.0:$PORT" -w 3
```

I dit it.
When starting the app on Heroku, I can see in heroku logs that it's crashed because of a `Unknown command: 'run_gunicorn'` error.
Indeed, typing `heroku run python manage.py help` let me see that the command does not exist.

What's going on?

here is an extract of `heroku run pip freeze`:

```
Django==1.7.6
gunicorn==19.1.1
newrelic==2.46.0.37
```

Comment: What did your Procfile previously look like?

Comment: it was `web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi` but I just found a workaround writing: `web: newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi`. It seems to work normally but I hope there is no downside writing it that way and not following the heroku doc.

Comment: Yes the point of that doc is just that you add the `newrelic-admin run-program`, not what goes after it.